# REST and RESTful - videos or pod casts

Tags: rest

I am looking for podcast or videos on REST and RESTful.

Ideally they should cover the basics & the more advanced topics

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's short and very basic, but check out [Intro to REST](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCcAE2SCQ6k) from the [GoogleDeveloper](http://www.youtube.com/user/GoogleDevelopers) channel.

For podcasts, check out the ThoughtWorks IT Matter podcasts <strike>[REST - Part 1 of 2](http://podcast.thoughtworks.com/itmatters/thoughtworks_004_REST_01.m4a)</strike> and <strike>[REST - Part 2 of 2](http://podcast.thoughtworks.com/itmatters/thoughtworks_004_REST_02.m4a)</strike> (audio links broken; summaries are still [here](http://www.thoughtworks.com/what-we-say/podcasts.html)) where Martin Fowler, Chris Stevenson, Jim Webber, and Sriram Narayan talk about REST.

Also, there's the "[Stefan Tilkov on REST](http://www.se-radio.net/podcast/2008-05/episode-98-stefan-tilkov-rest)", and maybe the "[Web Services with Olaf Zimmermann](http://www.se-radio.net/podcast/2008-02/episode-85-web-services-olaf-zimmermann)" episodes from [Software Engineering radio](http://www.se-radio.net/).

There might be something for you on the [RestWiki](http://rest.blueoxen.net/cgi-bin/wiki.pl) and the [REST wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) has lots of links to follow for more material.

I recently stumbled upon the "[RESTful Web Services](http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=F678FD2E7711FF9E)" video course by [Intertech](http://www.intertech.com/) but haven't checked it out. YMMV.

Comment: The Wikipedia article is in terrible shape, and the creator of REST, Fielding, says it isn't accurate.

Comment: SE radio links also broken now, will fix if I can track em down

Answer (score 4):

This is quite interesting article. I am afraid it is not a video or podcast, but thought it can be useful.

[How I Explained REST to My Wife](http://tomayko.com/writings/rest-to-my-wife)

Answer (score 3):

For basics, this is a good one : [Understanding REST](http://www.internet.com/video/?bcpid=1431564240&bclid=1433966034&bctid=1788889483)

There are some MIX [sessions](http://sessions.visitmix.com/) which you can find by searching for REST but most of them are based on WCF or Data Services.

Thoughtworks has a podcast on REST as well which can you get from [here](http://jim.webber.name/2008/03/23/b4309893-7047-47f9-babc-f841d7f0d8f7.aspx)..

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/qcon-tilkov-rest-intro) is one from Stefan Tilkov and [another](http://alandean.blogspot.com/2009/01/video-of-rest-at-ddd7.html) from Alan Dean

Answer (score 2):

If you interested in using REST with WCF and .NET I would recommend [Endpoint.TV](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/)

Answer (score 1):

Two other articles from infoq:
1. [A Brief Introduction to REST](http://www.infoq.com/articles/rest-introduction)
2. [REST Anti-Patterns](http://www.infoq.com/articles/rest-anti-patterns)

Answer (score 0):

Just read Fielding's [dissertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm) and his [blog](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven). His blog clears up some common misconceptions of REST. Beware of other information on REST that does not use authoritative sources - there's a load of misinformation out there.

Comment: I know he is the authority but its not exactly the simplest introductory material is it?  Fielding himself claims he has no time to explain it to implementors...he has bigger and better things to do!

Comment: It's important to know the authoritative source so that you only trust other things which reference and rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is a nice video on how to use REST in [Delphi aplplications](https://members.embarcadero.com/login.aspx?returnURL=http://cc.embarcadero.com/download.aspx?id=27274) by Jonathan Benedicto

> DataSnap REST Support for Web Applications
>   This presentation covers how to use the new DataSnap REST support for Web applications.

here is a link to a video by Marco Cantù  that has some nice [delphi examples](http://cc.embarcadero.com/download.aspx?id=27318) of rest clients

> 10 Rest Clients in Delphi
>   From Google to Amazon, from Microsoft to Yahoo, from Facebook to Twitter, most large Web sites offer a REST API and Delphi can easily query all of them. This session provides an overview of 10 REST client APIs showing how to integrate database data and Web applications. Creating Windows 7 applications in Delphi, since Delphi 2007, there has been improved support for new features of the Windows operating system, from Windows Vista to Windows 7. In this session, we explore some of the native features of the VCL and some extra APIs you can use.

Both these video come from the [code rage 4](http://conferences.embarcadero.com/coderage/sessions)